# Explanation on the different forms of proportion standard error and population variance of proportion (Stats)

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, standard-error

Let $\sigma^2$ be the population variance, $p$ be the population proportion, and $\hat{p}$ be the sample proportion.
My understanding is that $\sigma^2_p = p(1-p)$ (bernoulli trial) and the standard error is $$S_\hat{p} = \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}$$
It doesn't make sense to me why do the terms standard deviation and standard error have $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$ inside them while the variance doesn't have one.
Is there anything I'm missing? Perhaps some similar behavior with the variance of the mean or some properties of binomial?

Answer (score 1):

A sum of iid Bernouilli variables $X_i$ is a Binomial.
The variance of the Binomial distribution is $Var[\sum X_i] = n p (1-p)$.
Hence it is immediate that the variance of the mean of iid Bernouillis is $Var[\sum X_i / n] = Var[\sum X_i] / n^2 =  n p (1-p) / n^2 = p (1-p) / n$. And the standard deviation is the square root of the variance, $\sqrt{p (1-p) / n}$